# Adding a scope to a toolbar search in October

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

As per the documentation at https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/lists#adding-toolbar I have the following code:

**config_list.yaml**

```
toolbar:
    buttons: list_toolbar
    search:
        prompt: 'backend::lang.list.search_prompt'
        scope: byEmail
```

**Job.php** (model)

```
public function scopeByEmail($string, $query)
{
    return $query->where('email', 'LIKE', '%' . $string . '%');
}
```

Unfortuately, this produces an error: `Call to undefined method October\Rain\Database\QueryBuilder::byEmail()`

I don't understand why this error occurs, because I'm sure that I have the correct code in the model to deal with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this was caused by the fact that I have `searchable: true` for two different models in my `columns.yaml`

The result seems to be that because I have a `scope: byEmail` in the `config_list.yaml` I need to provide a `scopeByEmail()` method in all of the models that I have defined searchable fields for in `columns.yaml`